# js placeholder undefined message error

Tags: javascript, jquery, prestashop, placeholder

what's wrong on this js? it gives me the "Uncaught ReferenceError: msg_newsl is not defined" but it was a preset module of prestashop so it should be defined.

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#newsletter-input').on({
    focus: function() {
        if ($(this).val() == placeholder_blocknewsletter ||
$(this).val() == msg_newsl)
            $(this).val('');
    },
    blur: function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '')
            $(this).val(placeholder_blocknewsletter);
    }
});

var cssClass = 'alert alert-danger';
if (typeof nw_error != 'undefined' && !nw_error)
    cssClass = 'alert alert-success';

if (typeof msg_newsl != 'undefined' && msg_newsl)
{
    $('#columns').prepend('<div class="clearfix"></div><p class="' +
cssClass + '"> ' + alert_blocknewsletter + '</p>');
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('#columns').offset().top},
      'slow');
    }
});
```

**tpl**

```
<div id="newsletter_block_left" class="block" style="background-color:#efefef; text-align:center">
{*<h4 class="title_block">{l s='Newsletter' mod='blocknewsletter'}</h4>*}
<div class="block_content">
    <p style="font-size: 16px;text-transform: uppercase;padding-top: 10px;font-family: 'Questrial', sans-serif;">{l s='stay tuned, subscribe to our newsletter'}</p>
        <form action="{$link->getPageLink('index', null, null, null, false, null, true)|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" method="post">
        <div class="form-group{if isset($msg) && $msg } {if $nw_error}form-error{else}form-ok{/if}{/if}" >
            <input class=" inputNew form-control grey newsletter-input" id="newsletter-input" type="text" name="email" size="18" value="{if isset($value) && $value}{$value}{else}{l s='your e-mail' mod='blocknewsletter'}{/if}" />
            <button type="submit" name="submitNewsletter" class="nsp button button-small">
                <p>Subscribe</p>
            </button>
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="0" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: msg_newsl seems to be a variable which is not declared

Comment: @user2181397 so what should i change to make it works?

Comment: what is expected value of msg_newsl?

Comment: @user2181397 i have no idea it's a module that i found on prestashop. I've never edited it nor know how to edit a js, I'm still learning.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have:

```
{strip}
{if isset($msg) && $msg}
{addJsDef msg_newsl=$msg|@addcslashes:'\''}
{/if}
{if isset($nw_error)}
{addJsDef nw_error=$nw_error}
{/if}
{addJsDefL name=placeholder_blocknewsletter}{l s='Enter your e-mail' mod='blocknewsletter' js=1}{/addJsDefL}
{if isset($msg) && $msg}
    {addJsDefL name=alert_blocknewsletter}{l s='Newsletter : %1$s' sprintf=$msg js=1 mod="blocknewsletter"}{/addJsDefL}
{/if}
{/strip}
```

at /themes/your-theme/modules/blocknewsletter/blocknewsletter.tpl

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, on the tpl there was written `l s='your e-mail'` instead of `l s='Enter your e-mail'`